# ClassCastException in Java 11

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, dao, java-11

I have a JPA entity corresponding to a table in a database in which I have following

```
@Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(name = "detail", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
private List<CustomObject> customObjectList;
```

The detail column in the database is of type JSON, and the entry for the column in the database looks like:

```
[
  {
    "field1": "1",
    "field2":"2"
  },
  {
    "field1": "3",
    "field2": "5"
  },
  {
    "field1": "4",
    "field2": "6"
  }
]
```

Where `field1` and `field2` are attributes of `customObject`.

But, when I fetch them using a GET API, it gives me a class cast exception
Something like

```
LinkedHashMap cannot be converted to List<CustomObject>.
```

Any suggestion how to resolve it?

Comment: CustomObject class looks like Custom Object{String field1; String field2 //getter setter}

Comment: how you are fetching in get api? Because error clearly says `customObjectList` is being assigned to linkedhashmap return type.

Comment: I am trying to get using jpa repositiory findById method and getting this exception. Also i referred the below link:
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-collections-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: hi, kindly share your get call.That will give some idea where issue is

Comment: hi, to be specific, the error comes on this line var myList= customObjectJpaRepository.findById(id).get() Though we get the required piece of data from db, but it's in the form of linked hash  map, not able to cast it into List<CustomObject>